# Chrome Extension: "Could not load manifest," isn't finding file that's clearly in the uploaded folder

Tags: google-chrome-extension

[image]

My project folder and manifest.json file look like this, but I keep getting this error when trying to upload the extension:

[image]
I've tried to find an answer here and didn't see anything quite related. Tried duplicating the folder and re-saving the manifest in UTF-8 encoding, too. No luck. Please help ;A;

Thank you!

Comment: Remove `Crypto-Pulse/` from `"newtab"`.

Comment: That did it, thanks! Will mark as answered.